# placing the matched 2 different child elements xml values in a single line from xslt2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below input xml,

```
<GSKProductHierarchy>
<GlobalBusinessIdentifier>ZGB001</GlobalBusinessIdentifier>
<Hierarchy>
    <Material>335165140779</Material>
    <Level1>02</Level1>
    <Level2>02AQ</Level2>
    <Level3>02AQ006</Level3>
    <Level4>02AQ006309</Level4>
    <Level5>02AQ006309</Level5>
    <Level6>02AQ006309</Level6>
    <Level7>02AQ006309</Level7>
    <Level8>02AQ006309</Level8>
</Hierarchy>
<Hierarchy>
    <Material>335165140780</Material>
    <Level1>02</Level1>
    <Level2>02AQ</Level2>
    <Level3>02AQ006</Level3>
    <Level4>02AQ006309</Level4>
    <Level5>02AQ006309</Level5>
    <Level6>02AQ006309</Level6>
    <Level7>02AQ006309</Level7>
    <Level8>02AQ006310</Level8>
</Hierarchy>
    <Texts>
    <ProductHierarchy>02AQ006310</ProductHierarchy>
    <Language>A</Language>
    <Description>CREAM</Description>
</Texts>
<Texts>
    <ProductHierarchy>02AQ006309</ProductHierarchy>
    <Language>B</Language>
    <Description>CREAM</Description>
</Texts>
```

as per the requirement, xsl should check the matched value of GSKProductHierarchy/Hierarchy/Level8 in the GSKProductHierarchy/Texts/ProductHierarchy elements...and its should result as below flat file.

```
335165140779|02|02AQ|02AQ006|02AQ006309|02AQ006309|02AQ006309|02AQ006309|02AQ006309|02AQ006309|A|CREAM|
335165140780|02|02AQ|02AQ006|02AQ006309|02AQ006309|02AQ006309|02AQ006309|02AQ006310|02AQ006310|B|CREAM|
```

Right now I have the below xslt,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl set str java saxon">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="VarPipe" select="'|'"/>
<xsl:variable name="VarBreak" select="'&#xa;'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="GSKProductHierarchy/Hierarchy">
        <xsl:variable name="currentIndex" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Level8" select="Level8"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ProductHierarchy" select="../Texts[$currentIndex]/ProductHierarchy"/>
        <xsl:if test="$Level8=$ProductHierarchy">
            <xsl:value-of select="Material"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Level1"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Level2"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Level3"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Level4"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Level5"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Level6"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Level7"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Level8"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="../Texts[$currentIndex]/ProductHierarchy"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="../Texts[$currentIndex]/Language"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="../Texts[$currentIndex]/Description"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
                <xsl:value-of select="$VarBreak"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

can anyone please suggest what function should i need to use to get the desired result.

Regards,
Giri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your XSLT is not currently getting the desired output is because of these lines

```
 <xsl:variable name="ProductHierarchy" select="../Texts[$currentIndex]/ProductHierarchy"/>
 <xsl:if test="$Level8=$ProductHierarchy">
```

The code is assuming the `Texts` elements are in the same order as the `Hierarchy` nodes. But the first `Hierarchy` has a Level8 value of "02AQ006309", but this corresponds to the second `Texts` element.

If you do want to look up the `Text` elements but their `ProductHierarchy` then consider using a key

```
<xsl:key name="Text" match="Texts" use="ProductHierarchy" />
```

To use the key, you would just do this, for example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('Text', $Level8)/Language"/>
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="VarPipe" select="'|'"/>
<xsl:variable name="VarBreak" select="'&#xa;'"/>

<xsl:key name="Text" match="Texts" use="ProductHierarchy" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="GSKProductHierarchy/Hierarchy">
         <xsl:value-of select="Material"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="Level1"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="key('Text', Level8)/ProductHierarchy" />
         <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="key('Text', Level8)/Language"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$VarPipe"/>
         <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
             <xsl:value-of select="$VarBreak"/>
         </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've not output all the fields here, just to keep the XSLT more simple as an example. In fact, if you are indeed using XSLT 2.0, you could easily simplify you XSLT and still output all your fields. Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="VarPipe" select="'|'"/>
<xsl:variable name="VarBreak" select="'&#xa;'"/>

<xsl:key name="Text" match="Texts" use="ProductHierarchy" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="GSKProductHierarchy/Hierarchy">
         <xsl:value-of select="*" separator="{$VarPipe}" />
         <xsl:value-of select="key('Text', Level8)/*" separator="{$VarPipe}" />
         <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
             <xsl:value-of select="$VarBreak"/>
         </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much . the last xslt2.0 solution works perfectly. I will study the code and understand as I am beginner.